# StandardController of Account to show a pageblocktable of related child object from an extension errors out

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller, pageblocktable, extension

I have a object Competitor_Mapping__c that has lookup with Account. In the page, i have used standard controller of Account to fetch the current Account id from URL, used in a SOQL to populate a list of associated Competitor_Mapping__c  records, within an extension, which errors out **Error: Invalid field Competitor_Product__c for SObject Account**  Competitor_Product__c is a field of Competitor_Mapping__c.

Here is the code :

```
<apex:page StandardController="Account" extensions="inline1"  id="thePage"> 
    <apex:form id="theForm"> 
      <apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock"> 
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!records}" var="record" id="thePageBlockTable"> 
                 <apex:column width="25" style="background:pink;">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!record.Competitor_Product__c}" id="AccountTypeDOM"/>

                    <apex:facet name="header">CompetitorProduct</apex:facet>
                </apex:column>


                 <apex:column style="background: lightgreen;" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!record.January__c}" id="January" > 
                <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"  showOnEdit="saveButton" hideOnEdit="AddMoreButton"
                       /> 
                       </apex:outputfield>
                    <apex:facet name="header">January</apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
               <apex:column style="background:lightgreen;" >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!record.February__c}" id="February" >
                    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick"  showOnEdit="saveButton" hideOnEdit="AddMoreButton"
                       /> 
                       </apex:outputfield>  
                    <apex:facet name="header">February</apex:facet>
                </apex:column>
           </apex:pageBlockTable> 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons > 

                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"   id="saveButton" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Add More" action="{!AddMore}" id="AddMoreButton" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
        </apex:pageBlock>   
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the controller code :

```
public class inline1{

public List<Competitor_Mapping__c> records=new List<Competitor_Mapping__c>();
//public Map<ID, List<Competitor_Mapping__c>> records = new Map<ID, List<Competitor_Mapping__c>>();

//public List<Competitor_Mapping__c> records= [select id,Competitor_Product__c,January__c,February__c,March__c,April__c,May__c,June__c,July__c,August__c,September__c,October__c,November__c,December__c from Competitor_Mapping__c];
public List<Competitor_Mapping__c>lstAcct  = new List<Competitor_Mapping__c>();
public Boolean b{get;set;}
public Id Acc_Id {get;set;}

public List<Competitor_Mapping__c> getrecords()
{


return records;
}
/*Constructor*/
    public void inline1()
    {  

    }/*End Constructor*/

/*Constructor*/
    public inline1(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {  

   records= [select id,Competitor_Product__c,January__c,February__c,March__c,April__c,May__c,June__c,July__c,August__c,September__c,October__c,November__c,December__c from Competitor_Mapping__c where Account__c=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }
   /*End Constructor*/
  public PageReference Save()
    {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/inline1');

        for(Integer j = 0;j<records.size();j++)
        {
            lstAcct.add(records[j]);
        } 
        Update lstAcct;
        pr.setRedirect(True);
        return pr;
    }

    public PageReference AddMore()
    {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/inline1');

        Competitor_Mapping__c newRec=new Competitor_Mapping__c ();
        Insert newRec;
        pr.setRedirect(True);
        return pr;
    }

   public PageReference Del()
    {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/inline1');
         pr.setRedirect(True);
        return pr;
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you get this error? while loading the page or while hitting Save button? Please add debug log to find the location/line number where it breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Visualforce page compiler assumes the "record" in `{!record.Competitor_Product__c}` is the return value of the [getRecord](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_getRecord.htm) method of the standard controller rather than the `var="record"` of the apex:pageBlockTable. Hence the field name is looked for in Account not Competitor_Mapping__c.

(At runtime the opposite occurs: if a field that appears in both objects is used, the `var="record"` reference wins.)

Change the name you use  in `var="record"`  to some other name to fix.